# Windows 2003 SMTP virtual server, why emails are not delivered?

Tags: windows-server-2003, iis, smtp

Configured Windows 2003 as my email client, everything works fine with POP3 (i'm able to recieve emails), the problem is with SMTP and i can't figure out how to find where excatly this problem is, because email looks like it is sent, but recipients don't recieve anything...

i had some problems with relying, but fixed everything, and now i configured outlook express on the same machine, trying to send emails and it looks everything fine, email goes to SENT folder, no errors, but recipients (tried several diffrent) don't revieve any letters...

tried to test from the same machine with telnet like it described there http://support.microsoft.com/kb/153119 ant everything looks ok...

Answer (score 0):

Is your provider blocking traffic to port 25 destinations?

Are you able to perform the same telnet tests to other smtp destinations from the machine itself?

Comment: Agree with Keith.  You should perform the procedure specified in 153119, but from the Windows Server, to an external SMTP server.  Use a well-known public smtp server, such as google's gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com.  If the test results in a connection denied, your ISP or network team is probably blocking output SMTP.